# variable search and replace in vim

Tags: vim

I have a list of items that I want to add a method call to.  An example is easiest.  Here's what I have now:

```
 assists: 12,
 level: 14,
 deaths: 5,
 ...
```

I want to change that list to look like this:

```
 assists: build_average(:assists),
 level: build_average(:level),
 deaths: build_average(:deaths),
 ...
```

Is it possible to add that method call to the end of every line with the name of the key as the argument with a neat Vim expression?

Comment: It is possible - record a macro for the first line, and then apply it to the rest of the lines.

Comment: Of course it is. What did you try?

Comment: i'm working on the macro solution that @Kenney suggested now :)  I am a novice in vim, I admit, so I'm afraid I didn't know where to start

Comment: Regex would be best but vim regexes are often not standard..
My vim keystrokes are (starting at the first line): `qq0yypk/:ENTERd$abuild_average(ESCJ/ENTERld$a),ESCj2q`

Comment: @Kenney: You should put that into an answer. It is also a valid (and more intuitive, in my opinion) solution.

Comment: i agree, it's helpful to see how you approached this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you can record a macro:

```
q                   // record macro
q                   // assign it to letter 'q'
0                   // go to start of line
/:<ENTER>           // search for ':'
l                   // move cursor 1 position to the right
d$                  // delete to end of line (line is now 'assists:')
yyp                 // duplicate current line (cursor moves 1 line down)
k                   // move cursor up
A build_average(    // append " build_average("
<ESC>               // exit edit mode
J                   // join next line
A ),                // append " ),"
<ESC>               // exit edit mode
j                   // move 1 line down
q                   // stop recording macro
2@q                 // execute macro 'q' 2 times
```

Comment: kenney, you responded first and this is a really nice answer, so i'll give the check to you - Sven your answer is also very helpful, so thanks to you both

Comment: Here is a shorter one: `0wyw/:ENTERllvt,pa)ESCbibuild_average(:ESCj` ;)

Comment: :) Or this: `0vw"aywwcwbuild_average()<ESC>h"apj`

Comment: I'd use `f:` instead of `/:<Enter>` myself :-)

Comment: Vim golf: `qqywWCbuild_average(:<c-r>0),<esc><cr>q`. Note: start at the first word, `^`.

Comment: I had hoped that my comment would provoke this kind of responses. :)

Answer (score 5):

More of a regular expression:

```
:%s/\(\w\+\):.\+/\1: build_average(:\1),/
```

Note that this applies to all lines in your file. To only replace in a region, select the region (using `V`) and then use `:s` (which results in `:<,>s/...`).

Using more complex regular expressions in VIM can be tricky, because metacharacters are different from "normal" regular expression syntax (you need to write `\+` instead of `+`, but can use `.` without escaping it, for example). I found this guide very handy to refer to the special VIM-syntax of regular expressions: http://vimregex.com/#pattern

Comment: I get a `E486: pattern not found: \(\w+\):.+`

Comment: Sorry, always getting the escaping wrong. I fixed it in the answer. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: hi Sven, that's working for me as well as Kenney's macro, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

More regexp gymnastics:

```
:%s/\v(\w+):\s+\zs.*\ze,/build_average(:\1)/
```

Decrypting it:

- `:help \v`
- `:help \w`
- `:help \s`
- `:help \zs`
- `:help \ze`
- `:help \1`